# How to filter elements containing only specific repeated characters in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am looking to create a new dataframe that filters out redundant information from a previous dataframe. The original dataframe is created from looking through many file folders and providing a column of elements each containing a string of the full path to access each file. Each file is named according to trial number and score in a corresponding test folder. I need to remove all reiterations of scores that are 100 for each trial, however, the first score of 100 for each trial must remain.

With python Pandas, I am aware of using 
    df[df[col_header].str.contains('text')] 
to specifically filter out what is needed and the use of '~' as a boolean NOT.

The unfiltered dataframe column with redundant scores looks like this

```
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test1\trial1-98
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test1\trial2-100
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test1\trial3-100       #<- must remove
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial1-95
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial2-100
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial3-100       #<- must remove
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial3-100       #<- must remove
.
.
.
n
```

The expected result after using some code as a filter would be a dataframe that looks like this

```
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test1\trial1-98
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test1\trial2-100
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial1-95
\\desktop\Test_Scores\test2\trial2-100
.
.
.
.
n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one line should solve your problem.

```
df = df.loc[df["col"].shift().str.contains("-100") != df["col"].str.contains("-100")]
```

Update:

```
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace('\t','\\t')
df['test_number'] = df.col.str.split('-').str[0].str.split('\\').str[-2]
df['score'] = df.col.str.split('-').str[1]
df.drop_duplicates(["test_number","score"], inplace = True)
df.drop(["test_number","score"],1,inplace = True)
```

Check this solution out. The reason why I am doing the replace in very first line is your data contains `\t` which in programming is a tab delimiter.

Comment: This won't work if you have consecutive groups which are all 100 - it will remove items from the next group.

Comment: I am amazed at how quickly you responded, thank you. With minute modification it compiles and gives results, I am now checking to see if they are the desired results described.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the df.shift.str command. It appears that some of the scores below 100 are being skipped with this function, although it performs part of its task. The numbers containing 100s currently do not repeat if they gave the same test number (which is good)

Comment: it basically shifts the data by index. You can see how it works by creating a temporary dataframe of one column and do shift on that. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Comment: Could the df.loc function be overlooking multiple trial scores under the same test number below 100?

Comment: yeah. I just tested it. There is a bug. I will fix it and update the answer

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that case in the examples given. I appreciate your help

Comment: on the update given: the '\t' conversion is not needed with my real data because it is never an instance (not that you knew) so i negated that. the attribute error i receive is 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col''. referring to " df.col.str.split('-'). Python is v2.7

Comment: `col` is the column name. replace it with your column name

Comment: okay. I am following your logic, and will need to restructure your code based on my particular program. This will take a moment, your patience and help is much appreciated.

Comment: @rajatkabra, are you able to explain your usage of the consecutive str.split for the line of df['test_number']? also, why is it that you use 'str[-2]' and 'str[1]' for those lines? I searched for the syntax usage of str.split, but this tactic seems to be advanced

Comment: `[-2]` is for the `test` number while the `str[1]` is to extract the score after trial. `[-2]` is part of a nested split syntax, hence is different then the `[1]`

Comment: Am I able to share with you code that more specifically pertains to my situation? I am not yet a rank on stack overflow that allows me to create a chat.

Comment: each element really like this: \\Network\Scores\2018\18-559-1\18-559-1 T3-99 3-7-19.xlsx. The "test number" leads up to 'T3' and the score is separated by the '-' between 'T3' and '99'. Here, one particular '-' must be the separator of my two strings.

Comment: `df['score'] = df.col.str.split('-').str[5].str.split(' ').str[0]` this will get you the score for this example that you mentioned in the comments. I am little confused now about what exactly you need